# BeautifulSoup : how to show the inside of a div that won't show?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup and I have some sort of issue I do not understand, I think the question may have yet been answered, but none of the answers I have found help me in this case.

I need to access the inside of a div to retrieve the glossary entries of a website, however the inside of that div seems to "not show" at all with BeautifulSoup. Could you help me ?

So this is the html on the website :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="margin-top: 0px !important;">
<head>...</head>
<body>
<header>...</header>
<section id="glossary" class="search-off">
    <dl class="title">
        <dt>Glossary</dt>
    </dl>
    <div class="content">
        <aside id="glossary-aside">
            <div></div>
            <ul></ul>
        </aside>
        <div id="glossary-list" class="list">
          <dl data-id="2103">...</dl>
          <dl data-id="1105">
            <dt>ABV (Alcohol by volume)</dt>
            <dd>
              <p style="margin-bottom: 0cm; text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family: Arial Cyr,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: x-small;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-size: medium;">Alcohol by volume (ABV) is the measure of an alcoholic beverage’s alcohol content. Wines may have alcohol content from 4% ABV to 18% ABV; however, wines’ typical alcohol content ranges from 12.5% to 14.5% ABV. You can find a particular wine’s alcohol content by checking the label.</span></span></span></span><span style="font-size: medium;">&nbsp;</span></p>
            </dd>
          </dl>
          <dl data-id="1106">...</dl>
          <dl data-id="1213">...</dl>
          <dl data-id="2490">...</dl>
          <dl data-id="11705">...</dl>
          <dl data-id="1782">...</dl>
        </div>
        <div id="glossary-single" class="list">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="s_content">
        <div id="glossary-s_list" class="list"></div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And I need to access the different `<dl>` tags in the `<div id="glossary-list" class="list">`.

My code is now as follow :

```
url_winevibe = requests.get("http://winevibe.com/glossary")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
ct = url_winevibe.find("div", {"id":"glossary-list"}).findAll("dl")
```

I have tried various things, including getting to the descendants and children, but all I get is an empty list.

If I try `ct = soup.find("div", {"id":"glossary-list"})` and print it, I get : `<div class="list" id="glossary-list"></div>`. It seems to me the inside of the div is somehow blocked but I am not quite sure.

Does anyone have an idea of how to access this ?

Comment: Some elements are dynamically generated by scripts and won't appear on your `bs4`.  You'll need to use a different package like `requests-html` or `selenium` that can render these elements before parsing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Solution `url` is based on my research from where the data loads ! and i do see that it's loads via `XHR` from different `url` where the `JavaScript` rendered:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://winevibe.com/wp-json/glossary/key/?l=en').json()
hoks = json.loads(r)
for item in hoks:
  print(item['key'])
```

Second Solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://winevibe.com/glossary/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(20)  # wait 20 seconds for the site to load.
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'glossary-list'}):
    for dt in item.findAll('dt'):
        print(dt.text)
```

> you can use `browser.close()` to close the browser

Output:

[image]

Here's the final code which will get through all user requests via Chat:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://winevibe.com/wp-json/glossary/key/?l=en').json()
data = json.loads(r)
result = ([(item['key'], item['id']) for item in data])
text = []
for item in result:
    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://winevibe.com/wp-json/glossary/text/?id={item[1]}").json()
        data = json.loads(r)
        print(f"Getting Text For: {item[0]}")
        text.append(data[0]['text'])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Good Bye')
        break

with open('result.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for a, b in zip(result, text):
        lines = ', '.join([a[0], b.replace('\n', '')]) + '\n'
        f.write(lines)
```

Comment: This is definitely what I want, but if I wanted to get the whole glossary with the explanation, how would I do that ?

Comment: @Basile `print(r)` if that's what you looking for. or let me know if it's not

Comment: I am so sorry, but I only get ```<Response [200]>```with ```print(r)```. but otherwise, thank you so much for your answer, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203257/discussion-between--c-and-basile).

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη , great job. I love your solutions. I always learn a little something from your posts

Comment: @chitown88 you welcome :P love to help :P